# How to combine angular-cli to the java project (exist tomcat server)?

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I'm newbie in angular2.I got some problems when I using the angular-cli to my project.please give me some advise.

1.The angular-cli use "ng serve" to start the project,and it will start a server "localhost:4200" but my java project already has "localhost:8080",I was stocked,how should I do?(choose one or start two server)

2.After use the "ng serve",The app will automatically reload when you save.But my jsp file also need to compile to class.where can I set this process?

Answer (score 0):

1. You can use `ng serve` while you're building your app. When done, make the distributable:

   ng build -prod

It should create a `dist/` directory. You use that folder to distribute it with your Java app. See 2.

2. You'll have a build task to build your Java app, likely in maven, pom.xml. Setup this file to copy your `dist/` folder from 1) to y
   our *target/webapp* or similar. Then setup your project (web.xml?) to serve this folder on a url, like "/webapp".